# Using directives from other modules

Tags: angularjs

This seems super basic but for the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to use a directive that's defined in a second module (that I don't control).

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kikketer/e04kj546/3/

It's pretty basic but as you can see, the directive from the "other" module isn't being used.
I look to things like http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/getting-started and their line "Inject the mgcrea.ngStrapmodule into your application."

```
angular.module('myApp', ['mgcrea.ngStrap']);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: In your jsFiddle you just need to restrict your directive to an element as angular is expecting it to be used as an attribute. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/6Lwa8ohc/

Comment: note you are using Angular 1.0 in your jsfiddle which is very old. In Angular 1.3+ element directives are allowed by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bootstrap the module, set restrict: 'E' on the directive, and declare your controller to the module.

```js
var other = angular.module('other', []);

other.directive('something', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>Yep</div>',
    link: function() {
      console.log('something');
    }
  }
});

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['other']);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',
  function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
  });

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  var moduleEl = document.getElementById("my-app");
  angular.bootstrap(moduleEl, ['myApp']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<section id="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello, {{name}}!
    <something> Hrmmm </something>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you, I knew I was missing something obvious.  I also found that at least with this jsFiddle I didn't need to bootstrap it: http://jsfiddle.net/Kikketer/e04kj546/